# USB-C port not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, usb, 18.04, hardware

Lenovo Yoga 910 USB-C port is not working with Ubuntu 18.04.

`kern.log` doesn't output anything when I plug something in.

When I put the same hub to USB-C port that is meant to charge the battery it works. So I guess that that port is just disabled and I need to wake it up somehow. Because before reinstalling Ubuntu it was working just fine. Maybe I need some extra software (drivers) to fix that?

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 17ef:7205 Lenovo 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:e300 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0094 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b5a4 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Sounds like it could be a hardware failure rather than software. Do you know if it works in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem for two weeks and today I found a solution by simply buying another cable! This afternoon I received my 3rd "USB-C Male to USB-3 Female" adaptor and a flash drive showed up on the desktop! I don't know if I am allowed to write the make of this adaptor so I won't but the two previous ones from other manufacturers left me thinking that either the USB-C port on my new laptop was dead or that U!buntu 18.04 was incompatible with USB-C !!